# How to get table and column names from existing sql server snapshot/backup file

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, snapshot

We are designing a windows application where we need to 'Get **table and column names** from existing sql server snapshot file or backup file' .

Does anybody know how it can be done.
Please provide help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Backup file: no
- Snapshot: it's just another database

I reckon it's worth looking at [How Database Snapshots Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187054.aspx) to ensure your requirements make sense...

Comment: Hi,

Actually we are not going to use the backup & restoring techniques of sql server. 

Simply we want to allow user to select a backup/snapshot file and our application has to list & display the Tables & columns names which are there in those files. Here we will not use any sql Connection String.... we want to get info in offline manner.

Thanks for replying.

Comment: In which case, you can't. You need to have an active SQL Server database with a SQL connection string: there is no way to read a backup or snapshot file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just restore the backup programmatically, then check like you normally would (`information_schema`, etc)?

If not, all I can suggest is to look at http://www.idera.com/Products/SQL-toolbox/SQL-virtual-database/

Comment: Hi,

Actually we are not going to use the backup & restoring techniques of sql server. 

Simply we want to allow user to select a backup/snapshot file and our application has to list & display the Tables & columns names which are there in those files. Here we will not use any sql Connection String.... we want to get info in offline manner.

Thanks for replying.